# injecting models but the DataAnnotations using Interfaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, dependency-injection, data-annotations

I'm using an Interface to define my object in my MVC Controller, and using a Dependency Injection framework to inject various different concrete implementations.

The validation for the object is using DataAnnotations, but here comes the problem.

Because I'm using an Interface for the model which gets injected in to the controller, the DataAnnotations have to be against the interface, which is wrong because each concrete implementation that is being injected has its own DataAnnotations validation rules.

How can I ensure that the injected models DataAnnotations are being used when perform validation?

Comment: You have a big trouble! I think that you can archive this only using IValidatableObject, so every object will validate it self! I don't think that is possible to inject DataAnnotations without some complex hard coding!

Answer (score 1):

You should inject repositories into your controller using a DI framework, not models. Models should not be injected. Models is something that you retrieve/update through the repository interface that gets injected. The validation is performed on the models.

Comment: How would you use DataAnnonation to perform this validation, both at the UI and the business layer?

Comment: Personally I don't use any DataAnnotations. I use FluentValidaton.NET to perform validations on my view models and on my domain models. The rules are different, so I have different validators. I guess that you could also have a different set of DataAnnotations for your view models and your domain models.

Comment: Hum, confused, why would you want to have different validation at the UI to that at your Domain Model?  It is best practice to have a single common area for setting the validation, and then it is up to the UI to validate and then the domian model to validate too.

Comment: Simply because in most cases the validation logic is different.